# LibGDX - overlay texture above another texture using shader

Tags: libgdx, glsl, opengl-es-2.0, fragment-shader

I'm trying to mix two different textures(scene and clouds) which are obtained from FBO and draw them on quad.

```
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform sampler2D u_texture2;  
uniform vec2 u_res;

void main(void)
{   
vec2 texCoord = gl_FragCoord.xy / u_res.xy;

vec4 sceneColor = texture2D(u_texture, texCoord);
vec4 addColor = texture2D(u_texture2, texCoord);    

gl_FragColor = sceneColor+addColor;
}
```

glBlendFunc is

```
Gdx.gl20.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

I tried all combination of `glBlendFunc` and the combination above was the best one.

Creating FBOs:

```
fbClouds = new FrameBuffer(Format.RGBA8888, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), true);
fbScene = new FrameBuffer(Format.RGB565, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), true);
fbMix = new FrameBuffer(Format.RGB565, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), true);
```

creating clouds:

```
fbClouds.begin();
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0); // to make it transparent
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    modelBatch.begin(cam);      
    for (Integer e : drawOrder) {
        if(isVisible(cam, clouds[e])){
            drawLightning(e, modelBatch);           
            modelBatch.render(clouds[e], cloudShader);
            modelBatch.flush();             
        }
    }
    modelBatch.end();
    fbClouds.end();
```

render code:

```
Gdx.gl20.glDisable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
//Gdx.gl20.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
//Gdx.gl20.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
fbMix.begin();
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    mixShader.begin();
    fbScene.getColorBufferTexture().bind(1);
    mixShader.setUniformi("u_texture", 1);

    fbClouds.getColorBufferTexture().bind(0);
    mixShader.setUniformi("u_texture2", 0);

    mixShader.setUniformf("u_res", Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

    quad.render(mixShader, GL20.GL_TRIANGLES);

    mixShader.end();
 fbMix.end();
```

So, I get unexpected result(clouds have absolutely white color, though they should be grey):

[image: unexpected result]

In case if I use `modelbatch` to render clouds the result is as should be:
[image: expected result]

What is the right way to mix two textures without losing color?

Comment: It's turning bright white because you're adding gray to bright blue. But I'm not sure from your description exactly what's happening. Is that blend func what you're using when drawing to one of the FBO's, or what you're using to draw all your FBO's to the screen? Inside that fragment shader you used, you need to use the alpha of the cloud texture to multiply by the cloud texture and (1- alpha of the cloud texture) to multiply by the sky texture. But you'll need to make sure your clouds' FBO supports alpha and write to that alpha channel. Kind of convoluted. Maybe there's an easier way?

Comment: @Tenfour04, which formula should I use? Could you show me it based on my source code of shader? Clouds could be red or green, it doesn't matter. They are turned white in any cases!

Comment: I'm still not clear on what exactly you're doing. If you can clarify, I think I have a solution that would work. You show a fragment shader at the top. I think you mean you draw the sky and sun to one FBO, and the clouds to another FBO. Assuming that's right, how are you drawing the clouds, with a ModelInstance? And what is the clear color of the FBO you're drawing clouds on? And is the blend func you mention what you're using for the clouds to draw them into their FBO, or is it what you're using to draw your Quad with the two FBOs to the main buffer?

Comment: You're doing this to save on fill rate because the clouds overlap a lot, right? Is there any reason you can't draw the sky and sun directly to the main buffer and use only one FBO for the clouds only?

Comment: @Tenfour04, yes, I draw clouds using `ModelBatch` to one FBO which is downsampled twice and other elements of scene to another one. I have to do this to increase fps(as you can see on screenshots above). I use `Format.RGB565` for FBO of clouds and clear color is black. I use `blend func` to draw my Quad with the two FBOs to the main buffer. I don't know how to mix main buffer(the sun and the sky) with clouds FBO(in case if I draw them(sun and sky) directly in main buffer). So, I draw them both on Quad using shader above with `blend func`. I hope it's clear enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The blend function you use to draw the two FBO's to the screen should be irrelevant, because nothing shows through them, right? So blending should be turned off before you draw the FBO's, or you're wasting GPU cycles mixing the FBO's with your clear color.

The reason it turns white is that you are adding gray to blue without darkening the blue first. Normally when you draw a transparent object to the screen, you use a blend function like this: GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA. That means you are multiplying the sprite's color by its transparency (effectively darkening transparent colors) and you multiply the background by the inverse of the sprite's alpha (thereby darkening the pixels that will be added to the sprite's opaque pixels so they won't be too bright).

In your case, you want to emulate the same thing inside your fragment shader, since you are trying to blend two textures inside your shader before outputing them to the screen.

So if your cloud FBO had an alpha channel, you could do this in your fragment shader and you'd be good to go:

```
void main()
{   
    vec2 texCoord = gl_FragCoord.xy / u_res.xy;

    vec4 sceneColor = texture2D(u_texture, texCoord);
    vec4 addColor = texture2D(u_texture2, texCoord);    

    gl_FragColor = addColor*addColor.a + sceneColor*(1-addColor.a);
}
```

However, your cloud's FBO does not have an alpha channel so you need to change something.

One thing you could do is make your FBO color texture use RGBA4444 so it has an alpha channel, and then carefully draw your clouds so they also write to the alpha channel. This would be kind of complicated, because you'd have to use a separated blend function, where you select two different blend functions for the RGB and the A channels separately. I haven't done this before. Although it should be possible, I haven't even tried this method before because I think the 4-bit colors would look pretty lousy.

Alternatively, if your clouds are all going to be monochrome, you can encode your alpha information into one of the color channels. To do this you will need to customize the fragment shader you use to draw the clouds to the FBO. It would look something like this:

```
vec4 textureColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord);
gl_FragColor = vec4(textureColor.r * textureColor.a, textureColor.a, 0, textureColor.a);
```

What this does is put the cloud's monochrome color in the R channel with alpha pre-multiplied, and it puts the alpha in the G channel. We want to pre-multiply the alpha so we can simply add the encoded cloud sprite onto the scene. This is because when you draw something in front of an already-drawn sprite in an area that was translucent in the already-drawn sprite, you want to brighten the G-encoded alpha to make the pixel more opaque in the final FBO image. Since we are using pre-multiplied alpha, draw the clouds using the blend function GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA.

(This is a slight approximation because the G-encoded alpha of the destination is getting darkened a bit by the second part of the blend function, but I looked at the math and it seems acceptable. The approximation results in slightly more transparent clouds.)

So now the cloud FBO would look like a bunch of yellow if you drew it to screen as is. We just need to make a slight adjustment to our fragment shader above to use the encoded data:

```
void main()
{   
    vec2 texCoord = gl_FragCoord.xy / u_res.xy;

    vec4 sceneColor = texture2D(u_texture, texCoord);
    vec4 addColor = texture2D(u_texture2, texCoord);    

    gl_FragColor = vec4(addColor.r*addColor.g) + sceneColor*(1-addColor.g);
}
```

If you want to tint your clouds something other than pure gray, you can add a uniform color tint:

```
void main()
{   
    vec2 texCoord = gl_FragCoord.xy / u_res.xy;

    vec4 sceneColor = texture2D(u_texture, texCoord);
    vec4 addColor = texture2D(u_texture2, texCoord);    

    gl_FragColor = u_cloudTint*vec4(addColor.r*addColor.g) + sceneColor*(1-addColor.g);
}
```

Comment: It's really good answer. Thank you. If I understand you correctly, I should use FBO `Format.RGBA8888` for clouds with `Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);` to make them transparent. And arbitrary formats(i use RGB565) for other FBOs including `mix` FBO. Also, I have to disable `blending` at all when mixing. But when I mix the two textures, clouds seems transparent(I see the horizon through them) but have color now. I updated question, so you can see what I am doing.

Comment: So, after spending some time I have almost the same result as on screenshot above, but clouds have semi-transparent color. But I need to have opacity clouds. In other words, using this shader I lose depth of clouds.

Comment: Not sure which of my two methods you're using, the part before "Alternatively" or after. If you are using the first method, you will need to use separate blend funcs. You might have to use the first method to keep clouds from being slightly transparent. You would want a standard GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA for RGB, and GL_ONE, GL_ONE for the A. Also note that if targeting Android, you have to specify RGBA4444, not RGBA8888. Not all devices support RGBA8888.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know about `glBlendFuncSeparate` function. But when I applied `Gdx.gl20.glBlendFuncSeparate(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE, GL20.GL_ONE);` to clouds as you said, it started working almost as I wanted. Although, the color is a bit different from original and the clouds have black edging.

Comment: The black edges can be fixed by pre-multiplying alpha. So in your clouds shader, multiply the R, G, and B each by A when calculating gl_FragColor (leave A as is). The use GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA for the RGB blendfunc.

Comment: The black edges disappeared, but something went wrong with blending. some parts of clouds have absolutely white color and others have color which I specify. Seems to me I should have some tests to get proper result. Anyway, thank you again!

Comment: An alternative way to do pre-multiplied alpha is to do it in your texture file ahead of time instead of in your shader. Basically extract a copy of the alpha channel into a new image layer on top of your original layer and set the new layer to multiply.

Comment: I don't use Photoshop, just Gimp. The method might be similar. In Gimp: 1)Flatten image. 2) Copy alpha channel of image into a new grayscale layer. (In Gimp this can be done by going to Add Layer Mask -> Layer's Alpha Channel. Then select the mask and copy it and paste it as new layer.) 3) Set the new layer's Mode to Multiply. 4) Create a new layer filled with black and put it below the other two layers. 5) Flatten the image. 6) Add the alpha channel back to the image. (In Gimp you add an alpha channel. Paste the alpha image back in since it's still in clipboard from step 3, and Apply Mask.)